# Using Android Test Framework

Tags: android, testing

Android provides various packages for testing like

> ***AndroidTestCase 
>   ApplicationTestCase
>   InstrumentationTestCase
>   ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2                                               ActivityTestCase***

I need to know how to decide which package is best suitable for testing my app. Some info is provided in this link

http:[//developer.android.com/reference/android/test/package-summary.html](http:////developer.android.com/reference/android/test/package-summary.html)

But I need more clarity on this...

Answer (score 46, accepted):

***TestCase*** – Plain old JUnit test case.  It can be extended to test utility classes that are not tied to the Android framework.

> ***AndroidTestCase*** – It extends JUnit’s TestCase.  It’s a lighter
>   testing class compared to
>   ActivityTestCase.  It doesn’t need to
>   launch an activity to run it.  Its
>   getContext() method allows you to get
>   an injected context if you need one. 
>   Since you can get a context from this
>   class, you can inflate your UI objects
>   to test their behaviors.

***ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2*** – It’s the newer version of ActivityInstrumentationTestCase.  ActivityInstrumentationTestCase is deprecated in Android SDK 1.5.  It’s a heavier testing class compared to AndroidTestCase.  It provides UI and functional testing for a single activity.  You can get an injected activity that you are testing on by calling its getActivity() method.  The activity being tested is launched and finished before and after each test.

> ***ActivityUnitTestCase*** – It gives
>   the tested activity an isolated
>   environment.  When using it to test an
>   activity, the activity is not attached
>   to the system.  This gives you more
>   control over what kind of environment
>   that you want your activity to be
>   tested in.

***ApplicationTestCase*** – It provides testing for Application classes.  It can be used to test the life cycle of an application.

> ***InstrumentationTestRunner*** – The runner that runs the Android test
>   cases.

I just found this..Hope this helps for others...If u want more details like when and how to use, see the APIDemos test application in the samples directory within android SDK.

Comment: what about InstrumentationTestCase ?

Comment: ActivityUnitTestCase can't help any more for API24

Answer (score 9):

Please see the class hierarchy graph drawn by myself using PowerPoint.

The accepted answer gives enough info in words. I just to make it clear using graph :)

For the InstrumentationTestCase @Zorb asked, it's parent class for ActivityTestCase among others. It enables you to call the getInstrumentation method to get an instance of instrumentation so that you can operate application, activity, and so on.

[image: Class hierarchy graph drawn by myself]

Answer (score 3):

**INTRO**

To clarify your question and collocate the classes you are asking for, it is essential BEFORE to divide testing in two categories. ***JUnit tests*** (in theory plain Java) and ***Instrumentation tests*** (that also are part of the JUnit test package but allow you to test more SDK Android related functionalities).

Traditional JUnit tests isolate a section of code and run a test. Instrumentation tests access instead more inclusively the android components. BUT ALSO THE INSTRUMENTATION TESTS DERIVE FROM THE JUNIT PACKAGE although they are instantiated in the system even before any application code is run and this explain why are slower, furthermore they need an emulator or phone that run the app you are testing to be executed.

(Follow in Bold all the class you mention, but there are others even more used that I will write without without the bold character).

****FIRST PART**(Junit tests)**

***A)***  Junit tests that extend TextCase (are usually faster than Instrumentation, and combine well with Mock framweworks)

**AndroidTestCase**: It allows to have access to the Context of the Activity you are testing and their resources, it is a base class that extends more specialized subclasses, it is ideal to access databases, filesystem data. You can easily call getContext() and access the Resources without establishing a direct contact with the Activities as will be with Instrumentation tests.

**ApplicationTestCase** that controls the environment where you text the application, mainly the context and the life cycle. Other really useful extensions of AndroidTestCase allow you to control Loaders,Services,and Content Providers, but for some reason still not any Broadcast receiver that you can call it [indirectly][1] with  the method InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext() and then instantiating BroadCastReceiver. Also it is really common to use different Mock framework with Junit that is usually faster than InstrumentationTests

-.-.-.-.-.-.-.-.--

****SECOND PART**(Instrumentation tests)**

***B)*** **Instrumentation tests,** that extend TestCase
Are considered functional tests, focused more to insure that they work well with the user side, the View part of MVC.They are usually slower than the other mentioned category

**InstrumentationTestCase**  is a base class useful to send key events to UI to simulate QWERTY keyboard keys or DPAD buttons,also it launches the Activity that have to be tested, and even Intents

**ActivityTestCase** Usually is not used alone,it just has common code for the subclasses, but in the case you are not satisfied by the 3 classes that inherit from this one(see below) like a new future component you can use it by the time will not exist a TestCase class dedicated.

**ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2** is the most used Instrumentation class to write functional tests, from the constructor is invoked the instance of the Activity to test. Basically you call the activity with getActivity() and you can pratically run any method of that Activity.

ActivityInstrumentationTestCase, is deprecated, and ActivityUnitTestCase that although is under the Instrumentation is more similar to an unit test

Comment: I found this a useful answer. Too bad that those who are "late to the party" rarely get upvoted!

Comment: thanks for your appreciation Robert, never mind what matter is that the community that want to know  more scrolling a bit could benefit. Reputation is relative and writing structured posts helps the author to learn

Answer (score 1):

<s>I found [this tutorial](http://android.codtech.com/droidcon2009) from droidcon 09 to be really informative. Complete with downloadable working source code examples.</s>

Edit: The link seems to be dead, as pointed out in comments.

It walks through creating a Celcius to Fahrenheit temperature converter test-first using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, TestCase and AndroidTestCase.

Comment: Link to tutorial not valid anymore.