# Difference between InstrumentationTestCase and AndroidTestCase

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, junit

I've been looking at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2055455/281460 and it does a great job of explaining the different test classes available for unit/integration testing in Android. One thing it does not explain, though, is the difference between `InstrumentationTestCase` and the other test case classes, specifically `AndroidTestCase`.

Could someone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the docs:

> [InstrumentationTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestCase.html)
>
> A test case that has access to Instrumentation.
>
> [AndroidTestCase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/AndroidTestCase.html)
>
> Extend this if you need to access Resources or other things that
> depend on Activity Context.

`AndroidTestCase` is pretty well summarized via that link you posted. `InstrumentationTestCase` is higher up the class hierarchy from `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`. It's heavier weight than a plain `AndroidTestCase`, but it only exposes an `Instrumentation` object and no `Activity`, limiting its usefulness.

In reality, you'll probably never need this class, because it doesn't offer much (if any) performance advantage over `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, which offers access to an `Instrumentation` object itself. In any case, if you want to know what you can do with an `Instrumentation` object, check out [this](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/e15f6511b7a86622dbc63392830ecd61df4da6e0/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/tests/src/com/example/android/samplesync/authenticator/AuthenticatorActivityTest.java) or [this](https://github.com/android/platform_development/blob/e15f6511b7a86622dbc63392830ecd61df4da6e0/samples/training/testingfun/app/tests/src/com/example/android/testingfun/tests/lesson5/SenderActivityTest.java).