# on android unit testing, when to use test cases?

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I am a little puzzled by the testing in android.

I know that there are 2 types of unit tests:

1.local tests: run on local JVM, stored at `app/src/test/java`

2.instrument tests : run on android system, stored at `app/src/androidTest/java`, annotated with `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)`

The above-mentioned 2 classes are not extending TestCase and let's say this is the approach A in unit test.

And then I see test cases which are subclasses of TestCase, and they are placed alongside source code(in a separate package named xxx.test).  Let's say this is approach B.

It seems to me that what one wants in using TestCases(approach B), for example, confirming the text on a TextView can be achieved in instrument test+Espresso(approach A).

So I want to know when should I use local tests/instrument tests(approach A) and when should I use TestCases subclasses(approach B)??

Thanks in advance~~

PS:  [Using Android Test Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047261/using-android-test-framework/2055455#2055455)   while this thread explains uses of different TestCase subclasses which is like explaining the sub-approaches in my approach B, it does not answer my question.

Comment: Maybe use local test cases for classes completely unrelated to Android like model classes? Classes that don't require the "instrumentation" of the Android SDK?

Comment: There are different TestCase subclasses, some of them does not need android SDK, some of them does.   There is a small summary here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047261/using-android-test-framework/2055455#2055455)

Comment: So... You're answering your own question?

Comment: actually not...   I was asking when should I use TestCase subclasses and when should I use local tests/instrument tests?    Or what is the advantage of using TestCase subclasses and what is the advantage of using local tests/instrument tests.