# How to setup the environment for android instrumentation tests and make a sample Activity UI test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, testing

**Disclaimer**
Recently I’ve need to start testing my Android Applications and I’ve found many problems during my way through a successful test. The answers for my troubles weren’t easy to find, therefore, I’ve decided to share what I’ve learned from the community to the community.

> **Can I answer my own question?**
>   *Yes! Stack Exchange has always explicitly encouraged users to answer their own questions. If you have a question that you already know the
>   answer to, and you would like to document that knowledge in public so
>   that others (including yourself) can find it later, it's perfectly
>   okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer
>   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question*

Answer (score 0):

### Is there a better answer?

Despite the specification provided by Google in Android documentation, several problems can arise for those who lack experience with Gradle and Android Studio and want to start developing instrumentation tests.

### Understanding the subject

Before moving forwarding in this subject, take ten minutes and read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html) article. It will make you understand the basic concepts for testing your Application.

Understand the basic superclasses used in Android tests:

> - **TestCase** – Plain old JUnit test case. It can be extended to test utility classes that are not tied to the Android framework;
> - **AndroidTestCase** – It extends JUnit’s TestCase. It’s a lighter testing class compared to ActivityTestCase. It doesn’t need to launch
>     an activity to run it. Its getContext() method allows you to get an
>     injected context if you need one. Since you can get a context from
>     this class, you can inflate your UI objects to test their behaviors;
> - **ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2** – It’s the newer version of ActivityInstrumentationTestCase. ActivityInstrumentationTestCase is
>     deprecated in Android SDK 1.5. It’s a heavier testing class compared
>     to AndroidTestCase. It provides UI and functional testing for a single
>     activity. You can get an injected activity that you are testing on by
>     calling its getActivity() method. The activity being tested is
>     launched and finished before and after each test;
> - **ActivityUnitTestCase** – It gives the tested activity an isolated environment. When using it to test an activity, the activity is not
>     attached to the system. This gives you more control over what kind of
>     environment that you want your activity to be tested in;
> - **ApplicationTestCase** – It provides testing for Application classes. It can be used to test the life cycle of an application;
> - **InstrumentationTestRunner** – The runner that runs the Android test cases. I just found this..Hope this helps for others...If u want
>     more details like when and how to use, see the APIDemos test
>     application in the samples directory within android SDK.
>
> Credits for this answer, user Bharat Pawar
>   [Using Android Test Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047261/using-android-test-framework);

### 01 - Setup your Gradle Module

In your app gradle module import the following libraries:

```
defaultConfig {
   testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

dependencies {
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
   androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.0.0-alpha2'
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
   androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1') {
       exclude module: 'support-annotations'
       exclude module: 'support-v4'
       exclude module: 'support-v13'
       exclude module: 'recyclerview-v7'
   }
   androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
 }
```

### 02 - Write your activity test

This is a sample UI Test using JUnit4. In the examples found in the web, there will be people using JUnit3. This last one won’t make use of annotation but standard method names (starting with “test”), however, currently, Google tells you to use JUnit4 in your test

> In your JUnit 4 test class, you can call out sections in your test
>   code for special processing by using the following annotations:
>
> - **@Before**: Use this annotation to specify a block of code that contains test setup operations. The test class invokes this code block
>     before each test. You can have multiple @Before methods but the order
>     in which the test class calls these methods is not guaranteed;
> - **@After**: This annotation specifies a block of code that contains test tear-down operations. The test class calls this code block after
>     every test method. You can define multiple @After operations in your
>     test code. Use this annotation to release any resources from memory;
> - **@Test**: Use this annotation to mark a test method. A single test class can contain multiple test methods, each prefixed with this
>     annotation;
> - **@Rule**: Rules allow you to flexibly add or redefine the behavior of each test method in a reusable way. In Android testing, use this
>     annotation together with one of the test rule classes that the Android
>     Testing Support Library provides, suh as ActivityTestRule or
>     ServiceTestRule;
> - **@BeforeClass**: Use this annotation to specify static methods for each test class to invoke only once. This testing step is useful for
>     expensive operations such as connecting to a database;
> - **@AfterClass**: Use this annotation to specify static methods for the test class to invoke only after all tests in the class have run.
>     This testing step is useful for releasing any resources allocated in
>     the @BeforeClass block;
> - **@Test(timeout=)**: Some annotations support the ability to pass in elements for which you can set values. For example,
>     you can specify a timeout period for the test. If the test starts but
>     does not complete within the given timeout period, it automatically
>     fails. You must specify the timeout period in milliseconds, for
>     example: @Test(timeout=5000)

.

**Source**: https://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_android.html

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.espresso.contrib.RecyclerViewActions;
import android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers;
import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

import org.hamcrest.Matchers;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

import br.com.hole19.marvel.R;
import br.com.hole19.marvel.ui.commons.util.ActivityTemplate;

import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.*;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId;


/**
 * Created by Edgar on 04/05/2016.
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class TestActivityHomepage extends ActivityInstrumentationTestC;se2 <ActivityHomepage> {

    private static final String TAG = "TestActivityHomepage";


    private ActivityHomepage mActivity;
    public ActivityTestRule<ActivityHomepage> rule = new ActivityTestRule(ActivityHomepage.class, true, false);

    public TestActivityHomepage() {
        super(ActivityHomepage.class);
    }

   @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        mActivity = rule.launchActivity(intent);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPreconditions() {
        assertNotNull(mActivity);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoadMoreCharacters () throws InterruptedException {
        RecyclerView characters = (RecyclerView) this.mActivity.findViewById(R.id.characters);
        int previousSize = characters.getAdapter().getItemCount();
        characters.smoothScrollToPosition(previousSize);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        int newSize = characters.getAdapter().getItemCount();
        onView(withId(R.id.characters)).perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition(previousSize));
        assertNotSame(previousSize, newSize);
    }

    @Test
    public void openActivityCharacter () {
        onView(withId(R.id.characters))
                .perform(
                        RecyclerViewActions
                                .actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));

        assertFalse(mActivity.isRunning());
    }
  }
```

### 03 - Problems Investigation

During the process of creating the tests some problems may happen:

**Problems 01**: gradle finish with errors.
**Occurs when**: library conflict during gradle build;
**Description**: when importing  test specific libraries it may get in conflict with Application already existent libraries;
**Solution**: exclude the conflicting module from the conflicting libraries;

---

**Problems 02**: instrumentation error fails with timeout.
**Occurs when**: Launch instrumentation test;
**Description**: Intrumentation test don’t support existance of progress bar in the activity being testes;
**Solution**: In the tested activity, make sure to set the progress bar visibility to GONE after finishing the loading;

### More examples

If you want to check further examples of how to use test frameworks check out [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing) link;